# Image is not displaying when using Picasso in Android

Tags: android, android-studio, picasso

I am using Picasso for a few images and they are working fine, now I am attempting to get an image which I have displayed before but in a new activity. This one is not displaying, I only get the placeholder.

I have tried to remove the fit() and also changed it to resize(325, 275). I have checked if it is getting the url from Parse correctly and it is.

In my onCreate

```
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.change_photo);

    mSelectPhoto = (Button) findViewById(R.id.select);
    mSendPhoto = (Button) findViewById(R.id.send);
    mRetake = (Button) findViewById(R.id.retake);
    mDescription = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.description);
    preview = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.photoPreview);
    div = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.div);

    mFileType = ParseConstants.TYPE_IMAGE;
    currentUserID = currentUser.getObjectId();

    Log.d("============", "Retrieved " + currentUserID + " scores");

    ParseQuery<ParseObject> query = ParseQuery
            .getQuery(ParseConstants.KEY_USER_INFO);
    query.whereEqualTo(ParseConstants.KEY_USER_ID_INFO, currentUser.getObjectId());
    query.findInBackground(new FindCallback<ParseObject>() {
        public void done(List<ParseObject> objects, ParseException e) {
            if (e == null) {
                for (ParseObject thisUser : objects) {
                    currentPicture = thisUser.getParseFile("profilePicture")
                            .getUrl();
                }
            } else {
                Log.d("EditProfileFragment.jav", "Error: " + e.getMessage());
            }
        }
    });

    Picasso.with(this).load(currentPicture).fit().into(preview);
```

My XML

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#FFFFFF"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/description"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:text="Select a Photo To Get Started" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/photoPreview"
        android:layout_width="325dp"
        android:layout_height="275dp"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_margin="10dp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/description"
        android:contentDescription="profile picture"/>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/select"
        style="@style/AuthButton"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:paddingLeft="10dp"
        android:paddingRight="10dp"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/photoPreview"
        android:text="Select a photo"
        android:textColor="#FFFFFF" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/send"
        style="@style/AuthButton"
        android:paddingLeft="10dp"
        android:paddingRight="10dp"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/photoPreview"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/div"
        android:text="Change Picture"
        android:textColor="#FFFFFF" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/div"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_margin="1dp"
        android:visibility="invisible"
        android:layout_below="@+id/photoPreview"
        android:src="@drawable/button_divider"/>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/retake"
        style="@style/AuthButton"
        android:paddingLeft="10dp"
        android:paddingRight="10dp"
        android:visibility="invisible"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/photoPreview"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/div"
        android:text="Retake"
        android:textColor="#FFFFFF" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: problem can be that you are not getting the correct copy your url and paste it in browser check if the image shows.

Comment: I have checked that and it is the correct image

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You determine the url of your picture in an background task. Your Picasso-Load operation will simply be executed, before the url was loaded in your background task. Try to move your Picasso-Load operation inside your callback:

```
query.findInBackground(new FindCallback<ParseObject>() {
    public void done(List<ParseObject> objects, ParseException e) {
        if (e == null) {
            for (ParseObject thisUser : objects) {
                currentPicture = thisUser.getParseFile("profilePicture")
                        .getUrl();
                Picasso.with(Your_Activity.this).load(currentPicture).fit().into(preview);
            }
        } else {
            Log.d("EditProfileFragment.jav", "Error: " + e.getMessage());
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: Have tried that but I get a problem with the `this` part. States `with (android.content.Context) in Picasso cannot be applied to Parse.FindCallback`. Its weird because I used the exact code in another part of the app and it works perfectly

Comment: Thanks, this was exactly what I needed

Answer (score 0):

Change your code like this so that you can know if some error occurred while loading the image.

```
Picasso.with(this).load(currentPicture).placeholder(R.drawable.ic_launcher).error(R.drawable.ic_launcher).fit().into(preview);
```

If the ic launcher is displayed instead of original image probably got memory exception try .resize() and remove .fit().

Comment: I have replaced it with the following code as just the placeholder was showing:         `Picasso.with(this).load(currentPicture).error(R.drawable.ic_launcher).fit().into(preview);`. I have also resize it to 50 by 50 and still nothing.

Comment: what is your currentpicture url is it http or https